# 3D Identity LUT table in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to generate an blank identity lut in C++ the function `generate_table()` takes `size`, `domain_min` and `domain_max` as arguments. The function calculates the base for the lut from it's arguments and then starts a series of loops to populate the table.

```
 const float base = (domain_max - domain_min) / (lut_size - 1);

    for(int channel = 0; channel < lut_size; ++channel) {
        for(int slice = 0; slice < lut_size; ++slice) {
            for(int line = 0; line < lut_size; ++line) {
                std::array<float, 3> lut_line = {

                    (channel == 0) ? line * base : 0.0f,
                    (channel == 1) ? slice * base : 0.0f,
                    (channel == 2) ? channel * base : 0.0f

                };
                m_luttable.push_back(lut_line);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't figure out the structure of the nested loops to correctly generate the LUT. I'm getting the correct number of lines generated but the structure of each line is incorrect, surely there is a better way than adding a conditional statement for each channel iteration.

see example of output of first 34 lines:

```
0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.0625000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.1250000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.1875000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.2500000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.3125000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.3750000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.4375000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.5000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.5625000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.6250000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.6875000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.7500000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.8125000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.8750000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.9375000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
1.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.0625000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.1250000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.1875000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.2500000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.3125000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.3750000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.4375000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.5000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.5625000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.6250000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.6875000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.7500000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.8125000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.8750000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.9375000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
1.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
```

see desired output from correct example:

```
0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.0625000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.1250000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.1875000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.2500000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.3125000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.3750000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.4375000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.5000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.5625000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.6250000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.6875000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.7500000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.8125000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.8750000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.9375000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
1.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.0000000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.0625000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.1250000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.1875000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.2500000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.3125000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.3750000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.4375000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.5000000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.5625000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.6250000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.6875000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.7500000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.8125000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.8750000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
0.9375000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
1.0000000000 0.0625000000 0.0000000000
```

can anyone help with the correct syntax for the loop

Comment: solved! as simple as 
 line * base,
 slice * base,
 channel * base

Answer (score 0):

I got mixed up with the loop definitions:

It's easier to think of them as RGB

line * base,
slice * base,
channel * base